# MPI time measurement got affected by other user?

Tags: c++, time, ssh, mpi, cpu

I am measuring time in my MPI code like this:

```
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPIt1 = MPI_Wtime();

// my code

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPIt2 = MPI_Wtime();
MPIelapsed_inverse = MPIt2 - MPIt1;
```

I am logging into the lab computer with ssh and I run my program. However, these days I am running a really long experiment (it takes about 1 or 2 days to get completed). Yesterday night, another user logged in and did some heavy tasks too, which resulted in loss of the CPU from mine project for some time.

Will this affect my time measurements, or will `MPI_Wtime()` still report the actual elapsed time? I mean regardless of the other user.

Comment: That's what distributed resource managers were invented for: submit a job request, get resources granted exclusively, and run your computations unaffected by what other users do.

Comment: Yeah, but from Mark's answer, I think I should re-run my experiment @HristoIliev.

Comment: @HristoIliev you know better than that!  it's a help, sure, to have dedicated nodes, but the other nodes in the cluster can still chew up network bisection bandwidth or storage I/O.  Our field is not mature enough yet to allocate those resources as part of our 'qsub' command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MPI_Wtime` reports 'wall-clock' or 'elapsed' time.  If another user's program takes clock cycles from your program then the elapsed time of your program, from start to finish, will increase.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thus, I should run the experiment again, thanks Mark!